# How to validate field in InfoPath against separate SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I have two SharePoint Lists. One is a simply a list of items with a title and description, the other is a list of requests which contain a workflow. These requests are requests for adding or updating items in list A.

I want to validate the Title field on the add new item form for the Request List. I'm wanting to check that the Title does not already exist in List A.

I know can set the properties to only allow unique values on the Title for List A but as these request are going into a separate list I am not sure how I can check to see if the item already exists in List A.

I am creating the forms for the Request List in InfoPath.

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough idea, but you could load in List B into your data form and set a textbox to the value of the list, filtered by the title field from list A.  If the field is blank then you know it doesn't exist already.

This blog can help with the loading and filtering of the list data:
http://pravahaminfo.blogspot.com/2011/05/filtering-sharepoint-list-data-using.html